# Terminal not printing python code on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I made a small python file on my desktop for fun, and I'm frustrated to find that no values are being returned. Here is the code from the file:

```
def calc(x):
    chance =1
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        chance *= ((365-i)/365)
    return chance * 100

string = calc(23)
print string
```

And here is what I type into the terminal:

```
cd Desktop #where file is located 
python py.py #py is the name of the file
```

And this is what it returns:

```
0
```

Comment: This should work.  Make sure you're executing the right file with `cat py.py` in your shell?  Also, "end me?"  It's not so dire as that, is it?  

Answer (score 2):

Since `365` and `i` are integers, you are performing [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), which only returns the "whole" part of the result. Since `365-i` is lesser than `365` dividing the two will result in `0`, and continuously multiplying it by anything will still give `0`.

You could use the `365.0` notation to use floating point division, which will eventually generate the result `46.1655742085`:

```
chance = 1
for i in range(1,x+1):
    chance *= ((365.0 - i) / 365.0)
    # Floating point^-----------^
```

Answer (score 1):

Well so on your first iteration your i = 1. 365-1 = 364. 364/365 = 0 because it is integer division in python. So the answer will always give you 0 unless you change it to allow for you to give a float.

Changing 365 to 365.0 will give you your answer

```
chance = chance * ((365-i)/365.0)
```

I just changed the 365 to 365.0 and I got

```
2.23071139399e-05
```

As my output

Comment: Ohhhhh of course. Thanks, that was the issue.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct in Python2.x.  When a/b and a is less than b, result is 0.

Modify 365 to 365.0 it will cast the division result to float

```
   chance *= ((365-i)/365.0)
```